# How to capture user email in MS Teams with Bot Framework Composer

Tags: botframework, azure-bot-service, bot-framework-composer

I am developing chatbot using Azure bot framework composer and working on MS Teams now. I could capture user's username using **telemetry track event with property of ${turn.activity.from.user}**.

**My question is how to capture the user's email address in MS Teams ???**

Answer (score 0):

Email isn't supported through "turn.activity.from" object. According to [feedback](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-Composer/issues/5261) from the product team, you'd need to generate runtime to modify your code and add [custom action](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/composer/how-to-add-custom-action#export-runtime).